# WPF Combobox SelectedIndex

Tags: wpf, combobox, selectedindex

I am trying to use a WPF combo box to change a timer.
Currently, I have in an observable collection
15 mins
30 mins 
45 mins.
1 hour.

If the user clicks 15 minutes, then a timer will start counting down.
But my problem is, once the user clicks 15 minutes, the combo box won't let me pick 15 minutes again to reset it.
I have to click on another item such as 30 minutes, then I can click 15 minutes.

This is using XAML, I was wondering if there is any quick fix to this.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you could also handle the ComboBox `DropDownClosed` event to start your timer.

Answer (score 0):

what event are you hooking onto to initiate your timer? i am guessing selecteditemchanged? if so then that will be the cause of the problem. try using the click event and get the selected item in your handler. if you post your code / xaml i will be able to give a better answer. you should be able to do what you are asking in xaml.